# How to load links of a div 1 into this div 1?

Tags: jquery

Could you please tell me how to load  links of a div 1 into this div 1 with Jquery ?

Is it the best way ? :

```
$("#inbox-div").on("click", "a", function (e) {
    $("#inbox-div").load($(this).attr("href"));
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: I would suggest disabling the original link as well, after the click.

Comment: Finaly the thing is that when it's a not a regular link like a Dynamic Tab, its not loading dynamically anymore. I mean it's refreshing in the div.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's good. Also you can make an optimization defining `$inbox` variable to avoid a twice jQuery call:

```
var $inbox = $("#inbox-div");
$inbox.on("click", "a", function (e) {
    $inbox.load($(this).attr("href"));
    e.preventDefault();
});
```